# Code First domain classes

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, ef-code-first, entity-framework-6

I am new to ASP.Net MVC and EF Code First. I'd like to create a professional Music sharing website. But I am afraid if I am true in Code First.Also I want to use simple membership or any other membership you suggest and I want to use layering in my solution. I should have the following Entities:

```
namespace MusicSite.Models
{
    public class Media
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public MediaType MediaType { get; set; }
        public string  FilePath { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
    }
}

namespace MusicSite.Models
{
    public enum MediaType
    {
        MP3=1,
        MusicVideo=2,
        Photo=3
    }
}

namespace MusicSite.Models
{
    public class MP3:Media 
    {
        public Artist Artist { get; set; }
    }
}

namespace MusicSite.Models
{
    public class Artist
    {
        public User User { get; set; }
    }
}

namespace MusicSite.Models
{
    public class User
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Username { get; set; }
        public string Password { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I don't know how to relate these entities. Can you please help?

Comment: Maybe you want to use database first?  It makes it very simple to setup the model, and then you won't have to worry about setting up the relationships.

Comment: there is a vs extension,can generate class from exsit database,also generate relationship config,you can try it,and see what generated;so you can learn how config the relation http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/72a60b14-1581-4b9b-89f2-846072eff19d?SRC=VSIDE

Answer (score 0):

Start by relating your entities in your model, for example:

```
public class Media
{
    public Artist Artist { get; set; }
}

public class Artist
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

If you allow EF to generate your database based on this model, you will find that the `Media` table will contain a column named `Artist_Id` which is a foreign-key reference to the `Artist` table.

If you decide instead to create you database in parallel (for example, by hand), then you will need to either design the database to correctly take advantage of [EntityFramework Conventions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj679962.aspx), or use [Data Annotations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg193958.aspx) or [EntityFramework Fluent Mappings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591617.aspx)..

My recommendation at this point - if you truly wish to pursue code-first development - would be to create the classes and use EF to [generate the database](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj193542.aspx).